# Specified value is not supported for the serverRelativePath parameter

Tags: csom, web-application

```
 var page = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(FileName);
 context.ExecuteQuery();
```

When this is executing I am getting an error:

> Specified value is not supported for the serverRelativePath parameter

I am giving full file path in this call.

Answer (score 9):

Use `ServerRelativeUrl`, eq. `/sites/site/libraryname/folder/filename.ext`. Function returned File object.

Comment: are you saying that instead of https://<companyName>.sharepoint.com/MyLIb/MyFolder/MyFile.txt we have to mention only path like ('companyName.sharepoint.com/MyLib/MyFolder/MyFile.txt')?

Comment: In your case `/MyLib/MyFolder/MyFile.txt` will be the `ServerRelativeUrl`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

`ServerRelativeUrl` is everything after domain name but needs to start with `/`.

```
// url -> https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/<sitename>/<libraryname>

var serverRelUrl = context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl;
// returns /teams/<sitename>
```

So for file it will be in above sample `/teams/<sitename>/<libraryname>/folder/subfolder/file.txt`

Comment: A huge piece of this for me was that it needed to start with /.

Comment: me too, a lot head-scratching on that one!